# Lubuntu Screen Locking Issue

Tags: lubuntu, screen, lock

I have a laptop running Lubuntu. When I leave it for about 10-20 minutes, the screen auto-locks. I can unlock it the first time, but I can not unlock it after that. Instead, I need to force reboot the PC.  I have disabled all power management, so the screen should stay on and unlocked at all times.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, lock-screen every 10minutes. I always managed to log back in though.

In my case, I had to set to "off" the light locker option in the 
Preferences > light locker settings

Hopefully it will fix the lockscreen.
About the other issue, which error do you get? In which way you can't log back?